# Can I use asphalt shingles as a base for a concrete slab?

Tags: shingles, asphalt, disposal

I am making a porch with 5 inch concrete slab on top. I also have at least 800 sqft of asphalt shingles removed. Can i use these shingles and stone and dirt to fill 180 cubic ft and then pour concrete on top and sides, thereby permanently burying them in concrete. similarly can use these asphalt shingles in the bottom of the concrete paving? I understand disposing them correctly is paramount, but is it wrong for them to be under concrete and surrounded by concrete blocks.

any thoughts?

thanks

Comment: ...A 5" concrete slab "on top" of the porch??.

Comment: Concern would using too much soft materials(shingles, dirt) in a base for a slab.

Answer (score 1):

No. They won't compact well, and they'll decompose and settle, especially if they're conventional organic mat shingles.